# path to "docker-compose.yml" as a parameter

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Today in order to launch my docker containers specified/included in my docker-compose.yml file,
I first go to the folder where the docker-compose.yml is located and then I type:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

and it works very well!

WHAT IF I wish to run that "docker-compose up" command from a different folder (not from inside the folder where docker-compose.yml is located):

I tried:

```
docker-compose up -d -f /data/....../docker-compose.yml
```

but that did not work as I received a warning that did redisplay all the possible options and "-f"  was not 1 of of the option listed.

So how do I specify a path to "docker-compose.yml" as a CLI parameter to my "docker-compose up" command ?

Comment: what is the error displayed?

Comment: What is being displayed is NOT an error message, but just a generic message starting with : 
Builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service....

and then 
Usage: up [options] [--scale SERVICE=NUM...] [SERVICE...]

Options:
..........

Comment: docker compose up command doesn't have -f parameter, so you can't give it basically. However, you can use -f with docker compose run, if it suits your setup, give it a shot.

Comment: Actually the option "-f" cannot be used with docker run, this is what I received as error message:
unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f

Answer (score 8, accepted):

docker-compose is pretty picky about which parts of the command take options. In this case, `docker-compose up` doesn't take a `-f` option.

However, `docker-compose` itself *does* take a `-f` option. Try running:

```sh
docker-compose -f /data/......./docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Comment: Is there a way to add this path permanently so that it does not need to be specified each time? eg to the system path?

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to use the -f flag with "up" for hours! Every other comment I saw was incomplete or flat wrong. What is the rationale for this picky order? I've never encountered this with other CLIs. Is there an explanation in the docs or a git issue thread?